# Remove all nils from a list with sublists in LISP

Tags: list, null, lisp

I have a list with multiple sublists. Some of them have NIL elements that i need to get rid of. I can only use basic functions (NOT, EQL, CONS etc..)

```
(defun trgni (lista)
  (cond 
    ((null lista) nil)
    ((not (atom (car lista))) (cons (trgni (car lista)) (trgni (cdr lista))))
    ((eql nil (car lista)) (trgni (cdr lista)))
    (t (cons (car lista) (trgni (cdr lista))))))
```

I have one problem with my code and it happens when i have a sublist that contains only nils. For example:

```
(trgni '((NIL ((7))) (8 (9 (10 ((11))) 12)) (13 (NIL NIL))))
```

my code gives me:

```
((((7))) (8 (9 (10 ((11))) 12)) (13 NIL))
```

Comment: "a sublist that contains only nils" Remember that NIL *is* the empty list, so `((NIL ((7))))`, for instance, is the same as `((() ((7))))`.

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor Yes, but the problem is that it has to be printed as () instead of NIL or else it won't be valid (rules from the homework).

Comment: @Bonne In Common Lisp, `NIL` and  the empty parentheses `()` are two alternative printed spellings for exactly the same thing:  they refer to the symbol called `"NIL"` in the `"COMMON-LISP"` package.    (It's possible to have your own `NIL` in your own package which isn't the `COMMON-LISP::NIL` symbol; that's a different issue).   There is no difference in meaning between `(NIL NIL)` and `(() ())`.

Comment: Since your objective is to learn (and not really get nils out of a tree), I would ask if you know the path your code is taking such that you leave behind a nil? I do. :) Hint: try (rgni '(13 (nil nil))). Use trace or print statements to see where you are going if you cannot work it out by hand executing the code. hth. ps: this is very important stuff to master erly on.

Comment: @kennytilton Well I see that the list is getting to the very end and since i tell it to send back `NIL` if the list is null that's what it does leaving me with `(13 NIL)` . But I don't see how this can be fixed since that return of `NIL` in the code is pretty important to end the recursion itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [the hyperspec](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/26_glo_9.htm#OPCP) `()` is just an alternative notation for writing the symbol `nil`, however since it's the exact same object CL will only use one notation when printing it. It won't be the alternative notation unless the particular implementation has it as a configurable feature.

In you function, when you process `car` you need to check if the result is empty. Something like this:

```lisp
(let ((a (trgni (car lista))))
  (if (null a)
      (trgni (cdr lista))            ; don't include this null value
      (cons a (trgni (cdr lista))))) ; include since it's not null
```

Note that this only works for nested lists like `'(1 (nil nil nil) 2)` which should become `(1 2)`, but what if the argument is `(nil nil nil)`? Then it won't have any sensible value except `nil` to evaluate it to as `nil` is the empty list.